# Elementary Sentence Construction

Tags: nlp

I am working in NLP Project and I am looking for parser to construct simple  Sentences from complex one, written in C# . Since Sentences  may have complex grammatical structure with multiple embedded clauses.
Any Help ?

Answer (score 0):

Text summarisation and sentence simplification are very much an open research area. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization) has articles about [both](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_simplification), you can start from there. Beware: this is hard problem and chances are the state of the art system is far worse than you might expect. *There isn't an off-the-shelf piece of software that you can just grab and solve all your problems*. You will have some success with the more basic sentences, but performance will degrade as you complex sentence gets more complex. Have a look at the articles referenced on Wikipedia or google around to get an idea of what is possible. My impression is most readily available software packages are for academic purposes and might take a bit of work to get running.